# My custom widget model in Django won't submit data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I created a custom widget for one of my form elements, and I have it rendered as a `div` where `contenteditable='true'`, because I am making a simple WYSIWYG editor for my site. 
Here is the custom widget

```py
class DivTextWidget(forms.Textarea):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None,renderer=None):
        super().render(name, value, attrs)
        flat_attrs = flatatt(attrs)
        html = """
        <div contenteditable='true' id='%(id)s' name='text'></div>
        """ % {
            'attrs': flat_attrs,
            'id': attrs['id'],
        }
        return mark_safe(html)
```

And now here is the Post model

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
```

There is more the models, but the rest isn't applicable to this.
And now here is my form.

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=DivTextWidget())
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','text','group','image','file','tags','spoiler','NSFW','tag']
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass text-title','placeholder':'Title'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PostForm, self).clean()
        title = cleaned_data.get('title')
        text = cleaned_data.get('text')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label = ""
        self.fields['text'].label = ""
```

Again, I removed all unrelated things from the form.

So in my HTML, I have the form all set up and I know it works because when I had the default Textarea, it all went through fine.

I know that `divs` probably don't go through forms at all, but I am just wondering if there is any way at all to make the div go through the form and get saved.

Comment: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. You could create some custom JS if you really wanted to hav a `div`?

Comment: Could you explain that to me a little bit more? Like convert a textarea to a div with JS?

Comment: I can, but quick question, can you not just change the div to a textarea?

Comment: No, because `textarea`s don't support contenteditable, in which you can bolden text and do other things with

Comment: Okay, no worries. Do you have some JS running on the page?

Comment: I was googling around trying to find a way, and came across another answer where I have a textarea with display none, and then use JS onsubmit to submit the data that's in the div to the textarea. I'm going to try it real quick

Comment: Nope. It didn't work for some reason. What was the way you were going to suggest?

Comment: Tried something else and it's now fully working :)